# Registering/Discovering custom jmDNS service type doesn't pass port

Tags: java, jmdns

I'm trying to register and later discover a custom jmDNS service type, in part it works well but I can't extract the port number or host from the received data. It comes as 0 as host as null.

Service registration:

```
// Register a service
ServiceInfo serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_myservice._tcp.local.", "example", 8888, "path=index.html");
jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
```

Listener for service discovery:

```
public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Service added: " + event.getInfo());
        ServiceInfo info = event.getInfo();
        int port = info.getPort();
        System.out.println("Port: " + port);
}
```

If I change the same code to use type _http it gets the port number correctly.

Is the usage of the port limited to certain types?

Answer (score 0):

Posting here for future reference. 
This was due to the version used.

Had to use a different repository with newer versions.